# Listbox with images leaks Memory crashes with OutofMemoryException

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 app, i have a page with lisbox where i am binding list of images to in the ItemTemplate with other data. As soon as I leave the page, i feel these images are not freeing up from the memory.

Below are code details:

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="userList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}" Tap="userList_Tap" Loaded="userList_Loaded">
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="220" Height="220" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Image x:Name="episodeImage" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="120" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Source="{Binding DefaultImagePath}" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="episodeName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,36" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="Auto" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Text="{Binding ImageName}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </StackPanel>
</ListBox>
```

C# data behind:

```
public class ImageHolder{
    public BitmapImage DefaultImagePath { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}


// list binding
List<ImageHolder> images=Utils.GetLargeImages();
userList.ItemSource=images;


public static List<ImageHolder> GetLargeImages(){
    List<ImageHolder> images= new List<ImageHolder>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ImageHolder hold=new ImageHolder();
            hold.ImageName=i+"";

            hold.DefaultImagePath = new BitmapImage
            {
                DecodePixelWidth = 120,
                DecodePixelHeight = 120,
                UriSource = new Uri("Image_"+i+".png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)  // this image is in 400x400 size
            };
            images.Add(hold);               
        }
     return images;
}
```

I am using DecodePixelWidth and DecodePixelHeight during image fetching in (GetLargeImages() method).

onnavigatedfrom method i am setting null to the Listbox. But doesn't helping it, after couple of times going in and out of pages my app is crashing with OutofMemoryException.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        userList.ItemsSource = null;

    }
```

Comment: Could you add the code to GetLargwImages?

Comment: question updated with requested method.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://blogs.codes-sources.com/kookiz/archive/2013/02/17/wpdev-memory-leak-with-bitmapimage.aspx

Comment: i have gone through the link, i understand if single image control is repeatedly used to load multiple images that solution is apt. In my case, i am loading multiple of images in the list - how to clear them from the memory. Do you mean, reassigning my listbox with empty image in the OnNavigatedFrom method?

Comment: Try assigning each BitmapImage in your ListBox an empty Memory Stream, like he did in his DisposeImage method. see if that work around works

Comment: did you find any soultion ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something that normally should not be done. By calling the Garbage collector.

```
            GC.Collect();
```

You cann also try when you navigate away to another page to remove navigation backstack which should remove all knowledge of your page and thereby force a reinstantiation of the list and page when going back.